# Db4o consulta a dos tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, db4o

```
    ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), BDempleded);

    // creamos departamentos
    Departamentos dept1 = new Departamentos(10, "CONTABILIDAD", "SEVILLA");
    Departamentos dept2 = new Departamentos(20, "INVESTIGACION", "MADRID");
    Departamentos dept3 = new Departamentos(30, "VENTAS", "BARCELONA");
    Departamentos dept4 = new Departamentos(40, "PRODUCCION", "BILBAO");

    // creamos los empleados
    Empleados emp1 = new Empleados(7369, "SÁNCHEZ", "EMPLEADO", 7902, "17/12/2017", 1040, 0, 20);
    Empleados emp2 = new Empleados(7499, "ARROYO", "VENDEDOR", 7698, "20/02/2017", 1500, 390, 30);
    Empleados emp3 = new Empleados(7521, "SALA", "VENDEDOR", 7698, "22/02/2018", 1625, 650, 30);
    Empleados emp4 = new Empleados(7566, "JIMENEZ", "DIRECTOR", 7839, "02/04/2018", 2900, 0, 20);

    // almacenamos en la base de datos
        //departamentos
    db.store(dept1);
    db.store(dept2);
    db.store(dept3);
    db.store(dept4);
        //empleados
    db.store(emp1);
    db.store(emp2);
    db.store(emp3);
    db.store(emp4);
    
    db.close();
```

Tengo estas dos tablas creadas y necesito hacer una consulta.
La consulta es: mostrar por pantalla todos los empleados que trabajen en el departamento 30 y mostrar el nombre del departamento.

esta es mi clase MAIN

```
    ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), BDempleded);

    Empleados empleados = new Empleados(0, null, null, 0, null, 0, 0, 30);
    ObjectSet<Empleados> resultadoEmpleados = db.queryByExample(empleados);
    
    Departamentos departamentos = new Departamentos(30, null, null);
    ObjectSet<Departamentos> resultadoDepartamentos = db.queryByExample(departamentos);
    
    
    if (resultadoEmpleados.size() == 0)
        System.out.println("No hay registros en el departamento 30...");
    else {
        System.out.printf("Número de registros: %d %n", resultadoEmpleados.size());

        while (resultadoEmpleados.hasNext()) {
            Empleados emple = resultadoEmpleados.next();
            Departamentos dept =  resultadoDepartamentos.next();
            System.out.printf("Numero empleado: " + emple.getEmp_no() + "\n" + "Apellido: " + emple.getApellido()
            + "\n" + "Oficio: " + emple.getOficio() + "\n" + "Direccion: " + emple.getDir() + "\n"
            + "Fecha alta: " + emple.getDate() + "\n" + "Salario: " + emple.getSalario() + "\n"
            + "Comision: " + emple.getComision() + "\n" + "Número departamento: " + 
            emple.getDept_no()+"\nNombre departamento: "+dept.getDnombre() +"\n"+"\n");
        }
    }
    db.close(); // cerrar base de datos
```

el problema es que solo me sale el primer registro y luego me da esta excepción

> java.lang.IllegalStateException

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas haciendo una consulta para traer a los empleados y el departamento en cuestión, el problema creo que cuando haces esto:

```
while (resultadoEmpleados.hasNext()) {
    Empleados emple = resultadoEmpleados.next();
```

Estas recorriendo en este caso los 2 empleados que pertenecen al departamento 30, como indicas en la SQL, hasta ahí bien, te muestra todo los datos correctamente del 1º registro.

Pero a la segunda vuelta del bucle `while()`, en la línea donde obtienes el departamento:

```
Departamentos dept =  resultadoDepartamentos.next();
```

Como tu consulta solo trae 1 departamento, en este caso el departamentos de VENTAS, al hacer `.next();` salta la excepción `java.lang.IllegalStateException` que significa que "se ha invocado un método en un momento ilegal o inapropiado"

Se me ocurre la opción de obtener (en este caso, ya que solo viene 1 departamento) el departamento antes del bucle `while()` y utilizarlo después como lo tienes, creo que podría funcionar.

```
 Departamentos dept =  resultadoDepartamentos.next();

 while (resultadoEmpleados.hasNext()) {
        Empleados emple = resultadoEmpleados.next();
        System.out.printf("Numero empleado: " + emple.getEmp_no() + "\n" + "Apellido: " + emple.getApellido()
        + "\n" + "Oficio: " + emple.getOficio() + "\n" + "Direccion: " + emple.getDir() + "\n"
        + "Fecha alta: " + emple.getDate() + "\n" + "Salario: " + emple.getSalario() + "\n"
        + "Comision: " + emple.getComision() + "\n" + "Número departamento: " + 
        emple.getDept_no()+"\nNombre departamento: "+dept.getDnombre() +"\n"+"\n");
 }
```